# A simple get request in react. What am i doing wrong

Tags: react-native

IM doing a simple get Request. I want to put the response in my state array.

```
export default function App() {
  state = { features: [] };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(featuresURL, oParam)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ features: data });
      })
      .catch(() => alert("Bad request"));
  }, []);
```

what am i doing wrong ?
Im completely new to react. Im just learning

In fact what im trying to achieve is get markers on my react native maps.

this is my code:

```
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(featuresURL, oParam)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json))
      .catch(() => alert("Bad request"));
  }, []);

  mapMarkers = () => {
    return this.data.features.map((feature) => (
      <Geojson
        geojson={feature}
        strokeColor="red"
        fillColor="green"
        strokeWidth={2}
      />
    ));
  };

  return (
    <MapView
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      mapType="mutedStandard"
      initialRegion={{
        latitude: 37.1,
        longitude: -95.7,
        latitudeDelta: 10,
        longitudeDelta: 45,
      }}
    >
      {this.mapMarkers()}
    </MapView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  map: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
  },
});
```

Comment: You are trying to combine class component `setState` functionality with functional component hook `useEffect` - use the (new) `useState` hook in functional components

Comment: componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://enigmatic-reaches-55405.herokuapp.com/reports')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ reports: data.reports })
      })
      .catch(console.error)
}

to be honest i was trying something like this. that how i got in useEffect

Comment: @nbokmans check my edit, if you can help me